# Cannot call jquery function using onClick in html

Tags: jquery, function, validation, submit, referenceerror

I am trying to implement login functionality. I am using form in my login.html and when user click on button it should check if fields are not empty and then use php to check if user exist in database. I have added reference to main.js

I get following error :  Uncaught ReferenceError: submitForm is not definedkontroller.php:89 onclick

login.html

```
 <div id="loginForm">
            <form id="loginSubmit" action="?mode=validate">

                <h2>LOGIN</h2>

                <h2>Username</h2>

                <div class="loginButton">
                    <input type="text" id="user" name="username" placeholder="username">
                </div>              

                <h2>Password</h2>

                <div class="loginButton">
                   <input type="password" id="pass" name="password" placeholder="password">
                </div>

            </form>


        </div>

        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="submitForm()">login</button>
        </div>
```

main.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 ...

function submitForm(){

    console.log("in submitForm");
    console.log($("#user").val());

  if ($("#user").val() == ""){
     $("#user").addClass("red");
  }

  $("#user").blur(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("red");             
  });                           

  if($("#pass").val() == ""){
     $("#pass").addClass("red");
  }

  $("#pass").blur(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("red");    
  });

  if( $("#pass").val() != ""  && $("user").val() != "" ){
        console.log("values are not empty");
       $("#loginSubmit").submit();
  }
  return false;
}


});
```

Comment: Posted a working fiddle link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

This will work ...

http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/tvrm4c0o/2/

You had this line without a hash symbol for the user id.. so fix that.

> if( $("#pass").val() != ""  && $(**"user"**).val() != "" ){

**HTML**

```
 <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="$(this).submitForm();">login</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
   (function($){

      $(function(){  
        //document ready

      });

      $.fn.submitForm = function() {

          console.log("in submitForm");
          console.log($("#user").val());

          if ($("#user").val() == ""){
              $("#user").addClass("red");
          }

          $("#user").blur(function() {
              $(this).removeClass("red");             
          });                           

          if($("#pass").val() == ""){
              $("#pass").addClass("red");
          }

          $("#pass").blur(function() {
              $(this).removeClass("red");    
          });

          if( $("#pass").val() != ""  && $("#user").val() != "" ){
             console.log("values are not empty");
             $("#loginSubmit").submit();
          }

          return false;
      };

   })(jQuery);
```

But honestly I see you are trying to validate input here.  You are going to have more problems once you get the onclick to fire so let me save you the trouble and show you the way I've been doing this.  I feel like this is the best way.  But I'm more than open to anyone else who can show me a better way.

> **Take your blur events out of the function.**
>
> - Move the code to the document ready section
> - Use $("input").is(':visible').on('blur', function() {
> - Check the value and the class on every blur
> - Add or Remove class of red depending on value and class existing

Now when they blur the input, it will check the value and turn red if appropriate.   You can also use `.on('change', function() {` so if they don't change the value, it won't fire the event.

```
  (function($){    
      $(function(){  
          //document ready
          $("input").filter(':visible').blur(function() {
              if ($(this).hasClass('red') && $(this).val() !== "")) {
                  $(this).removeClass('red');
              } else if (!$(this).hasClass('red') && $(this).val() === "") {
                  $(this).addClass('red');                     
              }
          });
      });            
   })(jQuery);
```

Next add this to your html

```
<input style="display: none;" type="submit" id="submitHidden" value="hidden">
```

Then use this to do the submit if everything checks out ...  This way you don't run into any issues with *.preventDefault()* because you don't need to use it.

```
$("#submitHidden").trigger('click');
```

*Or if you want to be super cool.  Set a timeout to check their input after 500-750 milliseconds idle and authenticate with ajax, if the login succeeds, log them in.  It would be nice if you could also remove the login button, but if they enter an invalid password on accident it will just sit there so they need to still be able to submit in the case they have entered invalid credentials.*

```
     function startTimer() {
         $(document).keyup(function(e) {
             clearTimeout(window.timer);
             window.timer = setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('ajaxSubmit');
                 if (ajaxAuthenticate()) {
                     alert("auto login in progress...");
                 }
             }, 2000);
         });

         $(document).mouseup(function(e) { 
            clearTimeout(window.timer); 
         });
     };

     $("input").filter(':visible').on('focus', function() {
         startTimer();
     });
```

This is how I personally would write your submit form function...

```
     $.fn.submitForm = function() {

         $("input").filter(':visible').on("happy", function() {
             if ($(this).val() === "") {
                 $(this).addClass('red');
             }
         });

         $("input").filter(':visible').trigger("happy");  

         if( $("#pass").val() !== ""  && $("#user").val() !== "" ){
             $("#submitHidden").trigger('click');
         }
    }
```

Here is my version in action (with auto-login).   Try using the username 'test' with a password of 'test' and then DO NOT hit the login button, just wait for a second.

[FIDDLE (autologin version)](http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/vcwd0of0/7/)

Answer (score 0):

keep the submitForm() function out of

```
$( document ).ready(function() { });
```

place the function below it

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create id for the button while removing the onclick event on the html element:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" id="submit">login</button>
```

Then, you can use jquery to handle the click event:

```
 $('#submit').click(function () {
 //working codes
 });
```

That's it!